# Order symbols: $f=O(g)$ then $f=o(g)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, perturbation-theory

I have a problem with an exercise from M. Holmes "Introduction to perturbation methods"

I'll write the definitions.

**Def:** Let $f=f(\epsilon),\quad g=g(\epsilon)$. We say $f$ is a "big Oh" of $g$ and write

\begin{equation}
f=O(g)\quad as \quad \epsilon \downarrow \epsilon_0
\end{equation}

If there are constants $k_0,\epsilon_1$ (independet of $\epsilon$) such that

\begin{equation}
|f|\leq k_0|g| \quad for \quad \epsilon_0<\epsilon<\epsilon_1.
\end{equation}

We say $f$ is a "little oh" of $g$ and write

\begin{equation}
f=o(g)\quad as \quad \epsilon \downarrow \epsilon_0
\end{equation}

If for all $\delta>0$ there exists $\epsilon_2$ (independet of $\epsilon$) such that

\begin{equation}
|f|\leq \delta|g| \quad for \quad \epsilon_0<\epsilon<\epsilon_2.
\end{equation}

now the exercise is the following:

**1.2. In this problem is assumed that $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ (meaning $\epsilon_0=0$)**

1. Show that if $f=O(\epsilon^\alpha)$ then $f=o(\epsilon^\beta)$ for any $\beta < \alpha$.
2. Blah blah not important now.

There is a theorem that states the following:

**Theorem1.3:**

1. If 
   \begin{equation}
   \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow \epsilon_0}\frac{f}{g}=L \quad -\infty<L<\infty,
   \end{equation}

then $f=O(g)$.

1. If 
   \begin{equation}
   \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow \epsilon_0}\frac{f}{g}=0,
   \end{equation}

then $f=o(g)$. 
But I dont think the theorem applies here. Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need Th 1.3. Just do it direct from the definitions. Essentially $\epsilon^{\alpha-\beta}$ provides the $\delta$ you need for the $o(\epsilon^\beta)$.

Comment: the $\delta$ or the $\epsilon_2$?

Comment: because if you mean $\epsilon_2$, the definition says that $\epsilon_2$ is independent of $\epsilon$

Comment: Given $\delta$ you can find $\epsilon_2$ so that $\epsilon^{\alpha-\beta}<\delta$ for any (positive) $\epsilon<\epsilon_2$.